# How does append becomes prepend when forget to fclose the file?

Tags: c++, fstream

I found this interesting behaviour in the following c++ program.

```
#include <fstream>

void append(std::string path, int i){
   FILE *out = fopen(&path[0], "a");
   fprintf(out, "%d\n", i);
   //fclose(out);
}

int main(){
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++) append("./text.txt",i);
   return 0;
}
```

where I forget to close the file in `append`.

Then the content of `text.txt` after one execution will be

```
2
1
0
```

other than

```
0
1
2
```

Once I `fclose` the file correctly, this effect will disappear.

I wonder how does this happen? BTW, I'm running it on a Ubuntu machine.

Comment: ***I wonder how does this happen?*** I believe its undefined behavior to have the same file open multiple times writing to the file.

Comment: @drescherjm, the behaviour is that append text becomes prepend text.

Comment: I don't see an `fstream` used anywhere in this code.

Comment: The files are closed/flushed in opposite order of opening them probably, but still, UB. `&path[0]` is a bad idea btw, it can cause UB as well, use `path.c_str()` or use the filesystem library for C++ rather.

Comment: You are witnessing the effects of buffering. Every open file will be closed and its buffers will be flushed when the program exits, but in what order is anyone's guess.

Comment: @NathanPierson Sorry, I thought this tag means I include the <fstream>...

Comment: His point is you included fstream but instead did not use an fstream. You used `FILE *out = fopen(&path[0], "a");` which is from the `c` language and not an fstream.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm new to C++ so I'm not familiar with the standard operation. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You may want to learn the basics of [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), a concept that's usually pretty surprising for people who haven't worked with C and C++ much. Essentially, there's some code you can write where the compiler can do absolutely whatever it wants when resolving it. When this happens, reasoning about _exactly_ why the compiler chose to do what it did is usually difficult and not very informative. Your code appears to be one such case.

Comment: @drescherjm oh, but it seems that my vscode raises an error that FILE is undefined if I don't include it.

Comment: @sichengmao `FILE` is defined in `<cstdio>`.  Your specific environment must coincidentally include <cstdio> when you include <fstream>.  That can not be relied upon, though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list -- bookmark that, @sichengmao! :)

Comment: Thanks for all of your kind suggestions!

Comment: Code is a description of program behaviour. The compiler takes the code, interprets the behaviour, and generates the machine instructions necessary to accomplish the described behaviour. If the described behaviour is open to multiple interpretations, watch out.

Comment: It it worth mentioning that `fopen` yields a *buffered file stream* object, not just file. So `fprintf` and similar functions are usually writing to the buffer and resent data does not get to the actual file until stream is flushed. Additionally, if you want to make sure that written data is really written to the disc then you may need to rely on some OS-specific API.